# Fisrt observable return after the second they have different timeouts

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I have 2 observables.

This is the method thats return the observable

```
const rxjs = require('rxjs');
const op = require('rxjs/operators');


const retornaObs = (arg, timeout) => {
    return rxjs.of(arg)
    .pipe(tap(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(res);
        }, timeout);
    }));
}
```

and the callers

```
retornaObs([1,2,3], 4000)
.pipe(op.switchMap(() => {
    return retornaObs([4,5,6], 2000);
})).subscribe()
```

When I do this, my return is `[4,5,6]` and then `[1,2,3]`, but I need the sequential return.

Comment: You shouldn't use `setTimeout`. It defeats the purpose of using streams. Use RxJs operators to delay emitions

Comment: this worked for me. I remove the timeout and put the `.pipe(op.delay(timeout))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a RxJS operator called **Concat** that maybe is what you need.

Take a look at it [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat).

In your case it would be something like this:

```
concat(retornaObs([1,2,3], 4000), retornaObs([4,5,6], 2000))
```

Note, however, that in order for it to subscribe to the second observable the first one needs to complete.

Comment: i use the code bellow
`op.concat(retornaObs([1,2,3], 4000).subscribe(), retornaObs([4,5,6], 2000).subscribe())`
and the return was the same

Comment: same happen with `rxjs.concat(retornaObs([1,2,3], 4000), retornaObs([4,5,6], 2000)).subscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

Just to simplify

i change the timeout to
`.pipe(op.delay(timeout))`

and call

`rxjs.concat(retornaObs([1,2,3], 4000), retornaObs([4,5,6], 2000)).subscribe();`

the result is `[1,2,3]...[4,5,6]`